Help me identify my kitchen countertops
Can you help identify what material these countertops are?

The pattern is fairly uniform
They don't seem to scratch easily
They don't absorb water
I've lived here for 13 years and never treated or sealed them with anything






We want to take better care of them, with appropriate cleaners, sealers, etc., but we aren't sure what to buy.

They appear to be granite, but some of the modern solid-surface materials are pretty convincing. I'm not sure we'll be able to say with confidence.

Looks like granite to me, specifically Ubatuba (which is a fairly common, low cost variety of granite).

One day, Ubatuba is going to be the green shag carpeting of the '00s.

I think you nailed it. Thank you!
